# awk - split only by first occurrence

Tags: bash, awk

I have a line like:

```
one:two:three:four:five:six seven:eight
```

and I want to use `awk` to get  `$1` to be one and `$2` to be `two:three:four:five:six seven:eight`

I know I can get it by doing `sed` before. That is to change the first occurrence of `:` with `sed` then `awk` it using the new delimiter.

However replacing the delimiter with a new one would not help me since I can not guarantee that the new delimiter will not already be somewhere in the text.

I want to know if there is an option to get `awk` to behave this way

So something like:

```
awk -F: '{print $1,$2}'
```

will print:

```
one two:three:four:five:six seven:eight
```

I will also want to do some manipulations on `$1` and `$2` so I don't want just to substitute the first occurrence of `:`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Without any substitutions

```
echo "one:two:three:four:five" | awk -F: '{ st = index($0,":");print $1 "  " substr($0,st+1)}'
```

The index command finds the first occurance of the ":" in the whole string, so in this case the variable st would be set to 4. I then use substr function to grab all the rest of the string from starting from position st+1, if no end number supplied it'll go to the end of the string. The output being

```
one  two:three:four:five
```

If you want to do further processing you could always set the string to a variable for further processing.

```
rem = substr($0,st+1)
```

Note this was tested on Solaris AWK but I can't see any reason why this shouldn't work on other flavours.

Comment: Nice solution +1, I would probably explicitly set `$2` and `NF=2` so `$3` won't still contain `three` ect `awk -F: '{n=index($0,":");$2=substr($0,n+1);NF=2;print $1,$2}'`

Comment: This solution gives $1=one $2=two $3=three etc.  `echo "one:two:three:four:five:six seven:eight" | awk -F: '{ st = index($0,":");print $1 "  " substr($0,st+1)}{print $2}'
one  two:three:four:five:six seven:eight
two`

Comment: @Jotne did you read the answer? Adrain suggest storing the `substr` in `rem` and using that. Also see my comment which addresses both your issues.

Comment: I maybe need some sleep :)

Comment: @Jotne - no problem it's easily done. sudo_O - thanks for the update and improvement. Unfortunately it's not in my nature to give out answers on a plate, if I've taken the time to answer a question then I'd like them to spend a little time understanding the solution.

Answer (score 9):

Some like this?

```
echo "one:two:three:four:five:six" | awk '{sub(/:/," ")}1' 
one two:three:four:five:six
```

This replaces the first `:` to space.
You can then later get it into $1, $2

```
echo "one:two:three:four:five:six" | awk '{sub(/:/," ")}1' | awk '{print $1,$2}'
one two:three:four:five:six
```

Or in same awk, so even with substitution, you get $1 and $2 the way you like

```
echo "one:two:three:four:five:six" | awk '{sub(/:/," ");$1=$1;print $1,$2}'
one two:three:four:five:six
```

EDIT:
Using a different separator you can get first `one` as filed `$1` and rest in `$2` like this:

```
echo "one:two:three:four:five:six seven:eight" | awk -F\| '{sub(/:/,"|");$1=$1;print "$1="$1 "\n$2="$2}'
$1=one
$2=two:three:four:five:six seven:eight
```

Unique separator

```
echo "one:two:three:four:five:six seven:eight" | awk -F"#;#." '{sub(/:/,"#;#.");$1=$1;print "$1="$1 "\n$2="$2}'
$1=one
$2=two:three:four:five:six seven:eight
```

Comment: OPs question is not on substitution. Its retrieving fields with delimiter

Comment: indeed, i than want doing some manipulation on $1 and $2. i will edit my question so it will be clear.

Comment: Updated my answer to get it to match the request.

Comment: update the question. i can not replace the delimiter. cause i can not grantee that the new delimiter will not be in the text

Comment: Why not?, You get $1 and $2 to what you need?  You can later print them out like this $1 ":" $2.  Please post the complete project and what you like to get out of it.  And if you have `one:two:three:four:five:six seven`, should `seven` be `$3` (space between six and seven)?

Comment: as it shows in the example. seven:eight should be part of $2.

Comment: Update again to give only $1 and $2

Comment: @Jotne I think you are missing the point. Using any printable character may be found in the text including `|` everytime you change the character used the OP will just change the example. This is stated in the question.

Comment: Then just use a value not found in the file.

Comment: @Jotne read the question, the OP knows how to do this method, they state they don't want to use this method. `#;#` is still a printable string that might occur in the file.

Answer (score 2):

The closest you can get with is with GNU awk's `FPAT`:

```
$ awk '{print $1}' FPAT='(^[^:]+)|(:.*)' file
one

$ awk '{print $2}' FPAT='(^[^:]+)|(:.*)' file
:two:three:four:five:six seven:eight
```

But `$2` will include the leading delimiter but you could use `substr` to fix that:

```
$ awk '{print substr($2,2)}' FPAT='(^[^:]+)|(:.*)' file
two:three:four:five:six seven:eight
```

So putting it all together:

```
$ awk '{print $1, substr($2,2)}' FPAT='(^[^:]+)|(:.*)' file
one two:three:four:five:six seven:eight
```

Storing the results of the `substr` back in `$2` will allow further processing on `$2` without the leading delimiter:

```
$ awk '{$2=substr($2,2); print $1,$2}' FPAT='(^[^:]+)|(:.*)' file
one two:three:four:five:six seven:eight
```

---

A solution that should work with `mawk 1.3.3`:

```
awk '{n=index($0,":");s=$0;$1=substr(s,1,n-1);$2=substr(s,n+1);print $1}' FS='\0'
one

awk '{n=index($0,":");s=$0;$1=substr(s,1,n-1);$2=substr(s,n+1);print $2}' FS='\0'
two:three:four five:six:seven

awk '{n=index($0,":");s=$0;$1=substr(s,1,n-1);$2=substr(s,n+1);print $1,$2}' FS='\0'
one two:three:four five:six:seven
```

Comment: echo "one:two:three:four five:six:seven" | awk '{$2=substr($2,2); print $1,$2}' FPAT='(^[^:]+)|(:.*)' results in: one:two:three:four five:six:seveive:six:seven

Comment: @Udy you are either not using `GNU awk` or you have an old version.. Which version of `awk` are you running?

Comment: mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996 :)

Comment: Oh wow! I clearly state you need `GNU awk` for this solution. What system are you on? You may already have `GNU awk` if not you should install the lastest `gawk`.

Comment: @Udy I have added a solution that should even work with old `mawk`.

Answer (score 1):

Just throwing this on here as a solution I came up with where I wanted to split the first two columns on `:` but keep the rest of the line intact.

Comments inline.

```
echo "a:b:c:d::e" | \
  awk '{
    split($0,f,":");           # split $0 into array of fields `f`
    sub(/^([^:]+:){2}/,"",$0); # remove first two "fields" from `$0` 
    print f[1],f[2],$0         # print first two elements of `f` and edited `$0`
  }'
```

Returns:

```
a b c:d::e
```

In my input I didn't have to worry about the first two fields containing escaped `:`, if that was a requirement, this solution *wouldn't* work as expected.

Amended to match the original requirements:

```
echo "a:b:c:d::e" | \
  awk '{
    split($0,f,":");
    sub(/^([^:]+:)/,"",$0);
    print f[1],$0
  }'
```

Returns:

```
a b:c:d::e
```